# Why do we put exit(1) in the C code even knowing that it will terminate the program abnormally.

Tags: c, return

Why are we putting exit(1) to terminate the program abnormally? Why do we want to terminate abnormally?

```
//Program exits itself
//Note that the example would terminate anyway
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Program will exit";
    exit(1); // Returns 1 to the operating system

   cout<<"Never executed";
}
```

Comment: Umm... because you have detected an abnormal state?

Comment: Not really clear what you want here, sorry....

Comment: Because whoever was working the keyboard when that code was written decided to write it that way. You're misunderstanding, anyway. `exit(1)` does not *terminate the program abnormally*. It exits the program and returns 1 to the operating system. Whether that's considered abnormal or not would  depend on what the program that reads that output decides.

Comment: Because the program didn't print a newline at the end of its output, which is abnormal behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem. Saying that `exit(1)` *terminates the program abnormally* is not a very accurate statement, and can lead to confusion. A better way to say it is that `exit(1)` **indicates** unsuccessful termination, i.e., it lets the user of the program know that something went wrong. It's simply a way to communicate the problem.

I don't actually think this is such a bad question, it just indicates the confusion of someone new to coding.

Comment: Exactly! A man new to coding. Actually, I am not being able to understand in which situations we are going to use exit(1). exit(0) is pretty clear. Intention to exit the program. But exit(1) or any other non-zero ???

Comment: OK, Sir, I have gotten my point in the following answer, posted by someone. Thank you to all contributed.

Answer (score 1):

The number that is returned from a C executable is returned to the environment.
If the SHELL is bash, you can capture the exit status of an executable with 'echo $?' from the command prompt.

Here is an example of a C code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int
 main(void)
 {
     FILE *fp;

     if( ( fp = fopen( "nonexistfile", "r" ) )== NULL ){
        exit(5);
     }

     if(fp) fclose(fp);

     return 0;
  }
```

This code is trying to open a file that does not exists.  So it will exit with status of 5.  Lets say the executable of this program is called "open_file".

When you run this executable and type "$?",

```
 >./open_file
 >echo $?
 >5
```

Here a bash script that runs this executable:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ./open_file
 exit_status="$?"

 if [ $exit_status -eq 5 ]
 then
     echo "FILE not there"
 fi
```

Now lets say you have 10 C executable programs that are similar to above C program but trying to open different files.
And lets say you want to keep a log file of which of these programs failed opening a file.

As a programmer, you can exit with different exit status number for different programs.

e.g.  exit(1); for executable #1
      exit(2); for executable #2
                   ...
      exit(10); for executable #10

From bash script, it can keep track of  exactly which executable failed from return value of an executable.

This example was to illustrate how you can coordinate the exit(n); from a C program with bash script that runs this executable.  (n represents a decimal value)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is usually to tell the operating system something unusual happened.  Typically, a program exits with a value of zero.  In Linux, you can use $? to see the value returned (i.e. 'echo $?').  You can use this value in scripts, etc. to check how your program terminated.